¿Cómo puedo esconder excluir dato de un select y enviarlo con js?
Buenas tardes tengo el siguiente problema, tengo un select multiple con algunas opciones excluidas en la vista del cliente (idTipoDesinEstrucTrans 7), pero necesito rescatar ese valor en el controlador,¿Cómo podría rescatar ese valor y excluirlo del select? adjunto parte de mi codigo:
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="small text-center d-block bg-light p-1">Estructuras</label>
  <select name="idTipoDesinEstrucTrans[]" id="multiple-checkboxes" class="form-control" multiple="multiple">
    <?php
      $query = $conn ->prepare("SELECT * FROM tipodesinfeccionestructuratransporte");
      $query->execute();
      $result = $query->fetchAll();
  foreach($result as $row):
      $idTipoDesinEstrucTrans = $row['idTipoDesinEstrucTrans'];
      $detalleTipoDesinEstrucTrans = $row['detalleTipoDesinEstrucTrans'];
   ?>
   
   <?php if ($idTipoDesinEstrucTrans != 3 && $idTipoDesinEstrucTrans != 4
                                        && $idTipoDesinEstrucTrans != 5 && $idTipoDesinEstrucTrans != 6 && $idTipoDesinEstrucTrans != 7) {?>
      <option value="<?php echo $row['idTipoDesinEstrucTrans']?>">
        <?php echo $row['detalleTipoDesinEstrucTrans']?>
      </option>

      <?php } ?>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
  </select>
  <input type="hidden" name="idTipoDesinEstrucTrans[]" value="7">
  <input type="hidden" name="unidadDesinfectadas[]" id="unidadDesinfectadas1" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="unidadDesinfectadas[]" id="unidadDesinfectadas2" value="1">
</div>

y el js:
<script>
document.getElementById('formConsumosPortuarios').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    var select = document.getElementById('multiple-checkboxes');
    var selectedOptions = Array.from(select.selectedOptions).map(option => option.value);

    if (selectedOptions.length === 0) {
        select.querySelector('option[value="7"]').selected = true;
        document.getElementById('unidadDesinfectadas1').value = '0';
        document.getElementById('unidadDesinfectadas2').value = '0';
    }
});


entiendo que este código esta adentro de un <form >   conmethod="POST"  o method="GET"   ¿esto es asi?

@Aleman si está por method="POST"

@Yussef la idea que tenía en mente es excluirlo del select y enviar un valor por defecto, en este caso sería "no se realizó", el motivo de hacer eso es porque quiero evitar errores por parte del cliente: por ejemplo: escoge varias opciones y además escoge no se realizo, y esto sería incorrecto, y lo que buscaba lograr es que se pudiera pasar ese valor a traves de un js o de otra manera

No se entiende qué quieres decir con esto: el motivo de hacer eso es porque quiero evitar errores por parte del cliente: por ejemplo: escoge varias opciones y además escoge no se realizo, y esto sería incorrecto. ¿Acaso no es mejor, para saber si el cliente eligió o no un determinado valor, verificar si en los datos enviados está ese valor o no? Da la impresión de que estás aplicando una lógica invertida que hace que te ahogues en un vaso de agua, creando un problema donde no lo hay. ¿Acaso el problema no es en este caso una lógica errónea?

@A.Cedano El motivo del porque lo pense así es porque el select no es requerido y además dentro del select hay un select all y preferí excluirle la opción pero además si es que no se seleccionón un valor, pasar como predeterminado ese valor

Precisamente, al recibir los datos puedes verificar si hay un valor posteado para el select y si no lo hay entonces asignar el valor por defecto.

puedes usar el atributo data-NombreDato="datoQueQuieras"
Quedara oculto para el usuario pero igual en el inspeccionar si podras verlo
algo como esto: "Opcion 1 "
como colocar dos value a un select option

Si esa es la respuesta a esta pregunta, entonces cerramos esta pregunta por duplicada...
